# SHGetSpecialFolderPath cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'

Tags: c++, winapi

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL,buffer, CSIDL_INTERNET,FALSE );
```

Error: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
The OS windows 7 64 bit and Visual Studio 2010. I want to run this code in both windows XP as well as Win7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are building targeting Unicode rather than ANSI. But you are passing an ANSI buffer. You can fix this by a number of means:

1. Using a Unicode buffer: `wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH]`.
2. Switch to targeting ANSI in your project config.
3. Call the ANSI function directly. It's called `SHGetSpecialFolderPathA`.

My preference would be to use a Unicode buffer, option 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build in both Unicode and ANSI/MBCS, use `TCHAR` instead of `char`:

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, buffer, CSIDL_INTERNET, FALSE);
```